# How to print in a Windows Universal C++ project

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app, uwp

I feel so dumb asking this question but honestly I can't understand why System namespace can't be used! What am I doing wrong? Is there any other way to print a single line in the output?
(I am using Visual Studio 2015)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> I can't understand why System namespace can't be used

Windows Universal app is totally different with traditional desktop app, please check [Windows Runtime APIs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211377.aspx) and [Win32 and COM API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br205757.aspx) which lists all Win32 and COM APIs supported for use in UWP apps.

> Is there any other way to print a single line in the output? (I am using Visual Studio 2015)

If you need to print message to Output window, use [OutputDebugString function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363362(v=vs.85).aspx) in UWP C++/CX project, adding #include  to access it, for example:

```
void CPPUWPApp1::MainPage::LogMessage(Object^ parameter)
{
    auto paraString = parameter->ToString();
    auto formattedText = std::wstring(paraString->Data()).append(L"\r\n");
    OutputDebugString(formattedText.c_str());
}
```

Usage:

```
LogMessage("Hello World!");
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do this directly:

```
OutputDebugString(L"Hello World");
```

Notice the L in front of the string, to convert it directly to LPCWSTR.